# Linux: How to find the device driver used for a device?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If my target has one device connected and many drivers for that device loaded, how can I understand what device is using which driver?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Just use `/sys`.

Example. I want to find the driver for my Ethernet card:

```
$ sudo lspci
...
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 01)
$ find /sys | grep drivers.*02:00
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/r8169/0000:02:00.0
```

That is `r8169`.

First I need to find coordinates of the device using `lspci`; then I find driver that is used for the devices with these coordinates.

Comment: `lspci -v` does it by itself.

Comment: `lspci -nk` will show you attached drivers. In general the sysfs is the right place to search for.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko thank you! This will be a *great* timesaver for me :-D

Comment: I know the OP asked for "drivers being used", but what if the driver is not installed nor being used? How to find out just by the `vendorID:productID`? Also, what if it is not a PCI device, and you only see it in `lsusb` for example?

Comment: @DrBeco: But if driver is not installed, what do you want to find? You should just google in this case

Comment: Well, not an option if you are trying to find the correct driver to load for a bunch of network cards that are not working (so, no google, unless you keep moving to another machine, or booting something that work, which takes time)

Comment: And if it's USB? Is there a generic way to do this? Looking at /sys or /proc or something?

Comment: `lspci -vk | grep -A 6 -i ethernet` but you have to adjust the number of lines printed after the matching line with `-A`.

Answer (score 45):

Here's a [little script I wrote](https://gist.github.com/JonathonReinhart/573694d541dc2108f7629aaa615cef3b):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in /sys/class/net/*; do
    dev=$(basename $f)
    driver=$(readlink $f/device/driver/module)
    if [ $driver ]; then
        driver=$(basename $driver)
    fi
    addr=$(cat $f/address)
    operstate=$(cat $f/operstate)
    printf "%10s [%s]: %10s (%s)\n" "$dev" "$addr" "$driver" "$operstate"
done
```

Sample output:

```
$ ~/what_eth_drivers.sh 
      eth0 [52:54:00:aa:bb:cc]: virtio_net (up)
      eth1 [52:54:00:dd:ee:ff]: virtio_net (up)
      eth2 [52:54:00:99:88:77]: virtio_net (up)
        lo [00:00:00:00:00:00]:            (unknown)
```

Comment: I much prefer reading links to finding/grepping. Nice solution.

Comment: Thanks! Way better than the unreliable 'dmesg|grep' (ring buffer...)

Comment: I'd like to find solution which would find also `veth` and other virtual drivers. IMHO the only solution is to use `ethtool` or `lshw`.

Answer (score 18):

`sudo lspci -v` will show it. like this:

```
$ sudo lspci -v
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro  Devices, Inc......
...
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon
```

You can also combine it with `grep` like this:

```
$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A 20 VGA
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to plainly use sysfs and doesn't want to deal with all these commands which eventually looks inside sysfs anyways, here's how:

say, what is the module/driver for eth6?  "sfc" it is

```
# ls -l /sys/class/net/eth6/device/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 22 12:30 /sys/class/net/eth6/device/driver ->
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/sfc
```

or better yet.. let readlink resolve the path for you.

```
# readlink -f /sys/class/net/eth6/device/driver
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/sfc
```

so... to figure out what are the drivers for all of your network interfaces:

```
# ls -1 /sys/class/net/ | grep -v lo | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -c 'echo -n {} :" " ; basename `readlink -f /sys/class/net/{}/device/driver`'

eth0 : tg3
eth1 : tg3
eth10 : mlx4_core
eth11 : mlx4_core
eth2 : tg3
eth3 : tg3
eth4 : mlx4_core
eth5 : mlx4_core
eth6 : sfc
eth7 : sfc
eth8 : sfc
eth9 : sfc
```

Comment: how is this one better than the one Jonathan Reinhart posted ?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225496/47663

Comment: Probably same... but I love one liner... I can easily adjust things right at the command line... just for those who don't have time to open a file and write a script.

Answer (score 5):

For USB based devices you can see the driver name by using the `lsusb` command:

```
lsusb -t
```

And/or you use `lshw` which enumerates the devices on all buses including USB, PCI, etc so you can see which driver it uses:

```
sudo lshw
```

Comment: FTR: the driver is shown at line titled `configuration`, for example: <code>configuration: <b>driver=btusb</b> maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s</code>

Answer (score 4):

When [`ethtool`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ethtool) is installed you can simply use:

```
$ ethtool -i enp2s0 | grep driver | awk '{print $2}'
r8169
```

where `enp2s0` is the device name. `ethtool` provides detailed information about the interface:

```
$ ethtool -i enp2s0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version: rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

In order to install on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt install ethtool
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `lsmod` command to get the status of loaded modules / devices drivers in the Linux Kernel.

For a specific device, you can use `dmesg |grep <device-name>` to get the details too.

Comment: Thanks. But if i loaded two drivers for a device with same major no and different minor no ,and if only one driver  is being used for the device ,how can I find which driver is used for that device?

Comment: perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096411/how-to-get-free-minor-number-for-a-linux-device-driver) SO question can help you further.

Comment: If your system has not been online so long that the ring buffer has re-started, sure dmesg | grep <device-name> will work ; this doesn't work on any of my routers, however.

Answer (score 0):

For me I needed a way to link network device names to driver pci names, here is a one-liner (adjust or remove the "grep ens" to whatever name network device name you want to search for)

`for i in $(ip -br addr show | awk '{print$1}' | grep ens); do echo "$i: $(ethtool -i $i| grep bus-info)" ; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inxi` with the relevant parameter. For example to see the network devices and the drivers you can use `inxi -N`

```
mint@computer:~$ inxi -N

Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet driver: e1000
  Device-2: Intel 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI type: network bridge
    driver: piix4_smbus
```

Some parameter you might want to use. To see the complete list check the [man page](https://manpages.org/inxi)

```
-A
    Show Audio/sound card information. 
-G
    Show Graphic card information. Card(s), Display Server (vendor and version number)
-N
    Show Network card information. With -x, shows PCI BusID, Port number.
```

Answer (score 0):

Watching /sys filesystem/ For example for device eth0, with command

```
ls  /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver -l
```

Output says the driver is linked to "virtio" driver

```
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 11 14:43 /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver -> ../../../../bus/virtio/drivers/virtio_net
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Monty Montemayor’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/420515/80216).