# how to verify the current network driver name on rhel machine

Tags: linux, rhel, drivers, network-interface

we have rhel 7.2 server  with intel network adapters

we want to verify the Driver name by linux cli command

we not sure what is the network driver that installed ( could be `i40e or e1000e or ixgbe/ixgbevf` etc )

so is it possible to find the *Driver name* that installed on the server? by linux cli

we try by

```
lshw -class network
```

but `lshw cli` not installed and we want to find other way

Comment: Related (though not specific to RHEL): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41817/315749, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83985/315749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse `lspci`’s output to determine which drivers are currently *in use* (not just installed):

```
lspci -vmmk |
awk '/^$/ { network = 0 } /(Ethernet|Network) controller/ { network = 1 } network && /Driver:/ { print $2 }'
```

Once you have the driver names, `modinfo` will give you more information, including the driver version:

```
sudo modinfo i40e | grep '^version:'
```

Comment: is it possible to find the driver version , for example in case we want to install the driver i40e-2.12.6.tar.gz  then latest version is Version: 2.12.6

Comment: See the update.