# Find out why linux kernel module was loaded

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

The debian backports 4.8 standard kernel loads the module `fjes` on my thinkpad T460s.

How can I find out why this module is loaded, i.e. which hardware triggers loading this module?

Comment: Kernel will detect new hardware and load this module on the boot. When kernel didnt enable this module.Kernel didnt load this module. Even kernel detected new hardware on the boot.

Comment: Actually you can run # lsmod to check all modules loaded. And you can check fjes module info with # modinfo fjes.ko.If I am not mistaken.Another users also post the question about fjes module.It called Fujitsu device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lspci -v. You will need to grep (probably with -i to ignore case) for your module shown in lsmod. e.g. to find r8169:

```
lspci -v |grep -i -A 4 -B 4 r8169
```

You can change the number of lines before and after (A, B) to your liking/needs.

I found another user had the same question. There is a [script here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/linux-how-to-find-the-device-driver-used-for-a-device) to find out.

Comment: No result, not with `lspci -nk`, too.

Comment: Check with lspci -v by itself. Question: is fjes showing up in lsmod? I think fjes is a Fujitsu Extended Network Device Driver. Did you check your ethernets/wifis/networks in the lspci output?

Comment: `lspci` only shows Intel devices and a Realtek one (SD card reader).

Comment: That's... pretty odd. Got on my debian machine, lspci shows everything. Are you doing this as root/elevated privileges? I will admit, I am not on a laptop, and do not have your kernel installed (I bet). I think the script on the link I posted could be modified to search all directories in /sys/class and print them. That may or may not help your cause.

Comment: My bet is that the module is loaded but not needed at all...

Comment: I also have this module loaded. I think it is being loaded because it's alias is being associate with other hardware that you actually have.

Comment: That would be `acpi*:PNP0C02:*`...

Comment: There are more busses than just PCI, and other kernel subsystems that won't list modules in lspci. Try lsusb, lshw, lsmod for example.