# How can I get more information about ACPI devices?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, acpi

Recently I noticed that my Linux installation was loading at least one module that seems unnecessary to my system. The module in question is `fjes`, for the FUJITSU Extended Socket Network Device Driver.

This module matches with the following devices in `/sys`:

- `/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/PNP0C02:03`
- `/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C02:01`
- `/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/INT3F0D:00`
- `/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C02:02`
- `/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/device:00/PNP0C02:00`

I want to know how I can get the following information about those devices:

1. What kind of devices are those?
2. What are their manufacturers?

For fairness, I have [another open question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335238/is-it-normal-that-a-modalias-matches-various-devices) related to this. But in that question I wanted to know *why* I had so many different devices with a single modalias. Now I want to make sure that none of them are really related to the `fjes` module. My ultimate intetion is to open a bug report, so I want to be sure I'm not overseeing something silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are *Plug and Play* devices, AFAIK named after the legacy from the ISA bus era, but today identified by ACPI.

You can get information about them using `lspnp` (with added `-v` option), or directly from the `/sys/bus/pnp/devices` or `/proc/bus/pnp` tree.

`PNP0c02` is a "motherboard resources" entry and `INT3f0d` seems to be a Intel Watchdog Timer. Googling for the name also often finds matching Windows drivers, which may help in identifying.

I guess all the classes should also be listed in the PCI standard, but I didn't check.