# Usb wifi adapter problem

Tags: wifi, drivers, usb, airmon-ng, airodump-ng

I have a usb wifi adapter (Edimax [EW-7612UAn V2](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/wireless_adapters_n300/ew-7612uan_v2)) with its driver installed on my parrot system and my computer's pci is not compatible with parrot .The problem is parrot says both adapters are disabled when i use normal wifi and when I use airmon-ng the usb wifi adapter works well and the computer's pci ,of course, doesn't work. when putting my pci in monitor and my usb wifi adapter in managed mode, network manager removes both of them from the wifi menu although the usb adapter is not in the monitor mode.

In other words, parrot won't recognize both adapters if the main pci isn,t compatible or recognizable. so, what should i do to force parrot to use the usb wifi adapter only ?

lsusb -v result:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 7392:7822 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x7392 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0x7822 
  bcdDevice            2.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 3 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x002e
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

screenshot of network manager

[image: screenshot of network manager]

result of rf-kill:

```
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

result of ifconfig :

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 34:64:a9:73:43:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 396 (396.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 396 (396.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: @roaima parrot says that both adapters are disabled while the usb wifi adapter is compatible with parrot and it works well with airmon-ng in monitor mode

Comment: @K7AAY i edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.Using instruction [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/linux-how-to-find-the-device-driver-used-for-a-device),I found that my pci uses "rt2800pci".I unloaded the module using the following command :

```
modprobe -r rt2800pci
```

It worked well and the usb wifi adapter started working,but this solution works only for one session once the computer reboots you will have to unload the module again, you can blacklist the module if you want the module to be unloaded all the time.